# Set margins from textviews programmatically

Tags: java, android

Im trying to make a view where there is a static margin between textviews that i have made programmatically, how can i make this happened? I tried alot and my

```
setMargins(viewEvent, 20, placeSum, 0, 0);
```

just setting margins top from the layout and as said i want to make margins to the above textview.

Here is my loop

```
int set=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < partEvents.length; i++) {
            RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) eventView.findViewById(R.id.eventRelativeLayout);
            TextView viewEvent = new TextView(getActivity());
            viewEvent.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.eventbg);

            viewEvent.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));



            String startHour = getHourFromString(partEvents[i][2]);
            String startMinute = getMinuteFromString(partEvents[i][2]);
            String endHour = getHourFromString(partEvents[i][3]);
            String endMinute = getMinuteFromString(partEvents[i][3]);

            viewEvent.setText(partEvents[i][0]+ "\n" +
            partEvents[i][1] + "\n"
            + startHour + ":" + startMinute + "-" + endHour + ":" + endMinute  );


            final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            int placeSum = (int) (10 + set * scale + 0.5f);
            setMargins(viewEvent, 20, placeSum, 0, 0);


            viewEvent.setTextSize(20);



            set=set+100;
            try {
                relativeLayout.addView(viewEvent);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

xml

<

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dividerView"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/temp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
    android:text="Event namn:"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:id="@+id/sum"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="Beskrivning:"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sum"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:id="@+id/startEvent"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="Tider:"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/description"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/dividerView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/temp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />


<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/eventScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dividerView"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/eventRelativeLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="510dp">


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: could you provide your layout xml file as well?

Comment: here have any hint how to solve it?

Comment: margins are layout params. you set them on the layout param object of the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Margin is set in the `LayoutParams` (e.g., `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` in your case) as

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom); 
viewEvent.setLayoutParams(params);
```

**Update**

If you need to add the `TextView`s vertically then use `LinearLayout` as

```
<!-- inside scrollview -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/eventLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

And programmatically as

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) eventView.findViewById(R.id.eventLinearLayout);

for (int i = 0; i < partEvents.length; i++) {

    TextView viewEvent = new TextView(getActivity());

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom); 
    viewEvent.setLayoutParams(params);

    // rest of your code

    linearLayout.addView(viewEvent);
}
```

Using `LinearLayout`, would automatic handling your `TextView` expansion and shrinking.

Comment: it solved a part of the problem but if i write a longer message in one of the textviews it starts to hide behind the textview below.

Comment: I get my data from google calendar api so i don't want to short the string